# Mock Activated Route With Params in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-activatedroute

### Question

How to mock `ActivatedRoutes` in my unit tests?

### Service:

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private knowledgeModelService: KnowledgeModelService
  ) {
    route.params.pipe(map(p => p.modelId)).subscribe((modelId) => {
      this.modelId = modelId;
    });
  }
```

### My unit test:

With mock class

```
  class ActivatedRouteMock {
    // params = of([{modelId: 'test1'}]);
    params = { paramMap: of( convertToParamMap( { modelId: 'test1' } ) ) }
  }
```

...

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ StatsComponent ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: ActivatedRouteMock
        },
```

I tried diff. approaches from:

[Angular2 RC5 Mock Activated Route Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376840/angular2-rc5-mock-activated-route-params)

[Angular2 how to Mock Activated Route Params subscribed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849487/angular2-how-to-mock-activated-route-params-subscribed)

[Unit test angular activate route correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729024/unit-test-angular-activate-route-correctly)

[Angular 4 - Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077725/angular-4-failed-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-activatedroute)

But I'm not getting anywhere.

### Err:

```
route.params.pipe is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it like that?

```
class ActivatedRouteMock {
    params = of( { modelId: 'test1' } )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried it but had a 2nd Observable in it which was wrong mocked so I thought it was still the first. My bad.